# Inversing label encoder doesn't work for neural network?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have a categorical variable (A,B,C) in my data frame. Then, I encoded it using Label Encoder to pass it to a neural network using Keras. Usually I would inverse this transformation on other algorithms in order to get the category name back, but for some reason this doesnt work with a neural network/keras? Is there a way to fix this?

EDIT: I have already converted these probabilities into class indicies, but the Inverse transform does not work on this for some reason so I cant get the original labels back

Comment: Can you provide us with a **minimal reproducible** example and possibly a sample of your dataset? What have you tried? Full **traceback** of Error you got when you use `LabelEncoder()` , `inverse_transform()` like [sklearn example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html#label-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which library of *label-encoder* you used, but I remember there is a label encoder in [sklearn](/questions/tagged/sklearn) that can transform the string to the number and vice versa. Check it out [`LabelEncoder()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

I give you here an easy example, it works 100% on my computer.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
y_data = ["Cat","Horse","Dog","Cat","Dog","Horse","Dog"]
encoder = LabelEncoder()
y_train = encoder.fit_transform(y_data)
print(y_train) # [0 2 1 0 1 2 1]

#now lets say you y_pred is:  
y_pred = [0,1,1,2,2,1]
#then you can inverse_transform it:
y_pred_labels = encoder.inverse_transform(y_pred)
print(y_pred_labels) #['Cat', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Horse', 'Horse', 'Dog']
```

Comment: Yes, I used this. the problem is that the inverse label encoder is not working.

Comment: It should work, have you tried to inverse transform a manual data to check if it works?

Comment: @TheEngineerProgrammer This should be a *comment* (not *Answer*)

Comment: will you demonstrate the process

Comment: I added an example, it works 100%